# How to delete a lot of objects from database

Tags: django, django-models

I trying to delete over 20,000,000 objects at once by executing:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(some_field__lt=100).delete()
```

But I can't, because of not enough memory (1GB VPS). Is it bad method or what? How to do it?

Comment: guess you are just out of memory and thats it... try doing it bit by bit. deleting objects uses more memory than one would think. can you narrow down the filter and do it in smaller steps?

Comment: theoretically I can, but I can't be sure how much objects can I delete at once, an how much will be in the query.

Comment: that i really do not know. it depends on you system specifications and on your filters ;) i guess you can delete some 1-5k objects at once, depending on how big they are. but you have to find some filters yourself, maybe query an additional property

Comment: Still wondering why all the objects are stored on a delete query...? We got around this using iterator() and .delete() on the individual objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I think it's better to use raw sql query https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM mymodel WHERE some_field < %s", [value])
```

Comment: You, you can write this as a management command, execute and forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try limiting what is being selected `MyModel.objects.filter(some_field__lt=100).only('id').delete()`

or if needed get the query and perform the query outside of django
`MyModel.objects.filter(some_field__lt=100).query`